# Ubuntu on Windows: How can I set the title bar to a remote server prompt?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running ssh from Ubuntu Bash on Windows to remote machines. When I ssh to another machine, is there a way to change the Title Bar of the window to match where I am logged in?

Something akin to the current method where it changes the title based on the directory I'm working in.

So if I ssh to server, the title bar would then show as user@serverA instead of user@local.

Comment: on cmd console the command is "title TEXT_ON_TITLE_BAR", but i wish to know the command in ubutu subsystem too

Answer (score 0):

Install '**xtitle**' package first:

```
sudo apt-get install xtitle

#or from ubuntu 16+
sudo apt install xtitle
```

Then run this command to change the bash window title:

```
xtitle SOME_TITLE
```